# Restore jailbroken iPhone 3G stuck in error 1015

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, restore, iphone-3g

I'm trying to restore a iPhone 3g I got that was jailbroken. I plugged it into itunes and hit restore and received the error 1015 that it could not be restored. I've tried using the tinyumbrella solution I believe I did it correctly but it did not work. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: ask different (pun intended).

Comment: Specifically, [Apple.SE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iPhone is not bricked. Use RecBoot, it is an application that helps a lot. [Here is a tutorial](http://absinthejailbreak.com/forum/fix-itunes-error-1015/).

Also, this site is for programming questions only. Try asking iPhone questions on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead.